# How to have several dropdown boxes on the same worksheet, with one of the options linked to a user form?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am working on a small project and I have encountered a problem. I need to insert several dropdown boxes on the same worksheet, and once an option has been selected it should appear in the cell. Also, if a specific option has been selected, then a user form should appear.

How can I accomplish this? I have tried the data validation dropdown, but am not able to use it for several cells.

Jook, thank you but the code provided does not work. I created combo box using the Developer, range (L2:L5) and cell link L1. Values are NO, YES, OTHER, ENTER DATA.
The code I used was the following in VBA in Sheet 1:
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
OnCboChange(ComboBox1)
End Sub
Private Sub OnCboChange (By Ref cboBox As ComboBox)
If cboBox.value= "OTHER" then
Userform1.Show
If cboBox.value= "ENTER DATA" then
Userform2.Show
End If
End Sub

I am not sure if I did something wrong, but the code does not read the above code, and I do not know how to associate this code to the combobox.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include details of what you've done so far. For instance; how you added drop down boxes, what specifically triggers the user form to appear, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To put a combo-box on to your worksheet, use the developer-tab and insert one, where you like. For further information, use google or ms-help, becasue this is widely covert.

By using the properties of your combo-box (right click), you can specifiy a `ListFillRange`, like `A1:A20`.

On the right-click menu, you can also select "view code", where you will be directed to a section like:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    'use this code for all your cbo-boxes, if it is the same for all
    OnCboChange(ComboBox1)
End Sub

Private Sub OnCboChange(ByRef cboBox As ComboBox)
    'check if a specific selection was made
    'If cboBox.value = "myValue" then
    If cboBox.ListIndex = 3 Then
      'specify what to do now
      MyUserForm.Show
    End If
End Sub
```